# What is the wrong with my code for query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

Please find below my code for get data from table

```
    $all_trades = FinalTrade::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->where('market_id', '=', $market_id)->get();


      $numbers_of_entries = $all_trades->count();
      $l=0;
      foreach ($all_trades as &$value) {
          $value = $all_trades->pluck('buy_rate') * $all_trades->pluck('quantities');
          $l++;
      }


      DD($l);
```

my `$all_trades->pluck('buy_rate')`and `$all_trades->pluck('quantities')` has array result.. how can i multiplying and get array result?

result of `$all_trades->pluck('buy_rate')` in browser.

```
Collection {#1186 ▼
  #items: array:12 [▼
    0 => 2205
    1 => 0
    2 => 50351
    3 => 0
    4 => 40
    5 => 1000
    6 => 500
    7 => 324
    8 => 2342
    9 => 2342
    10 => 234
    11 => 555656
  ]
}
```

actually i am trying to multiply play two row.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  In a eloquent collection, `pluck` will pull all the values of a specific key.

Comment: pluck result are in array.... as mentioned in question i want to multiply with another array result see: `$all_trades->pluck('buy_rate') * $all_trades->pluck('quantities');`

Comment: Yes, because you're calling pluck on the collection, how do you expect to multiply arrays?  Are you trying to multiply the buy_rate and quantities of EACH item in the collection?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: But with foreach only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$all_trades = FinalTrade::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->where('market_id', '=', $market_id)->get();

    $total =[];

  foreach ($all_trades as $value) {
      $total[] = $value->buy_rate * $value->quantities;

  }


  dd($total);
```

Comment: actually, i want result in array... but DD($total); is total.

Comment: not a error but.. i dont want to sum but i want result in array

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are calling pluck on the collection in your loop instead of utilizing the item of the collection.

When you have the item itself, you don't need a collection method:

```
foreach ($all_trades as $item) {
    $product = $item->buy_rate * $item->quantities;
}
```

You'd have to utilize the `$product` somehow, otherwise it will just be overwritten in each iteration of the loop but I don't know what you're trying to do with the product of this multiplication problem.   You most likely don't want to be assigning `$value` as a reference and overwriting it like you are in your question.

If you're trying to associate the product with the collection item, you can just add a new property:

```
foreach ($all_trades as $item) {
    $item->product = $item->buy_rate * $item->quantities;
}
```

Now every item in $all_trades will have a new property named product with the corresponding value.  Since objects are always passed by reference, you don't need to use `&$item`.

Comment: this is giving me result for only 1 array ... i want to result of all array

Comment: Yeah, how do you want that result?  Do you want a sum of the products?

Comment: i want result in array, same was in array

Comment: Ok... do you need it associated somehow or do you just want loose numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You might have better success if you actually multiply within the query:

```
 $all_trades = FinalTrade::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                ->where('market_id', '=', $market_id)
                ->select("*, (buy_rate*quantities) as total")
                ->get();
```

Then each of your entries will have the `total` property in addition to the actual entry so you can then do:

```
$all_trades->pluck('total');
```